# Create custom html input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, input

I want to create my own html numeric input and reuse it in my html page.
Declare something like that for example:

```
<input controlname="numberInput" type="text" onkeydown="return ValidateNumber(event);" onblur="ReturnToDefaultValue(this);" value="0"/>
```

and then reuse it in the following:

```
<div>
    <input type="numberInput" id="number1" />
    <input type="numberInput" id="number2" /> 
    <input type="numberInput" id="number3" /> 
</div>
```

Can someone offer something please?
Thanks

Comment: I don't think that is allowed for valid `HTML`. You could however add a `css class`, and use `jquery` to attach the events and other data.

Comment: Use `data-controlname="numberInput"` or a class instead.  Then, as mentioned, jQuery to find the elements and add the enhanced functionality.

Comment: @TryingToImprove Ok great so can you point me to a simple example of how doing it? I'm very new to html\javascript\jQuery. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add jquery to your page `<script src="jquery.js" />` Then paste you HTML, and add a script tag like this:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".controlNumber")
        .blur(function(e){ 
            ///blur stuff
        })
        .keydown(function(e) {
            //keydown stuff
        });
</script>
```

You input should then have a class named `controlNumber`

```
<input type="text" class="controlNumber" />
```

Using class also give you a easy way to style all the `controlNumber`'s

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to add an entire framework when you can just use `getElementsByClassName` and `addEventListener`

Comment: Question is tagged `jquery`

Answer (score 1):

Give your inputs a class.

```
<input type="number" class="special_input">
```

Then add the appropriate jQuery.

```
$(function() {
  $("input.special_input").keydown(function(event) {
    return validateNumber(event);
  });
  $("input.special_input").blur(function(event) {
    returnToDefaultValue(this);
  });
});
```

...for example.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to just add a class to the inputs and give them a normal `type` (like "text"). Then you can add the behaviour to it using JavaScript.

Example (using jQuery):

```
 $('.numberInput')
   .on('blur', returnToDefaultValue)
   .on('keydown', function(e) { validateNumber(e);});
```